# Syntax error on creating pgAdmin 4 Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I get an error when trying to make one of my columns a primary key. The error is:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2: ALTER COLUMN id TYPE integer (4);
^
```

My SQL for that table looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE public.recipes
    ALTER COLUMN id TYPE integer (4);
ALTER TABLE public.recipes
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

I am trying to learn node.js & postgresql and I am going through this course:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBw5E5DzAvE

but at 6min in he says you need to make the "id" column a primary key. To do this he unchecks a "read only" box, which pgAdmin 4 doesn't seem to have anymore? So the way I found was to go to the tabel "recipes"/right click/properties/Columns tab/Change "id" column to Primary Key = "yes". But when you then hit save you get the above mentioned error.

Any idea how to get rid of this error OR how to disable the "read only" on the SQL tab?

Comment: The `integer`  data type has no parameters: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT

Comment: Yeah but I can't edit anything in the SQL tab, how do I edit the SQL?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean with that. Just remove the parameter and run the SQL

Comment: I can't change the SQL, I can't remove the parameter, I physically cannot change the SQL

Answer (score 1):

The Query Tool allows you to run any SQL with pgAdmin 4.
Right click on your database in the browser and start the it. Copy Your SQL into the newly opened tab, remove the parameters "(4)" and run it.